# What is this generalized multivariable hypergeometric function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, special-functions

I'm looking for any kind of reference on a multivariable generalization of a (confluent) hypergeometric function.

To be specific, [Horn's List](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornFunction.html) is a list of 34 two-variable hypergeometric functions, 20 of which are confluent. Then one of these has the following series expansion:

$$\Phi_2(\beta, \beta', \gamma, x, y) = \sum_{n,m = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(\beta)_m (\beta')_n}{(\gamma)_{m+n} m! n!} x^m y^n$$

Here $(a)_n = \Gamma[a+n]/\Gamma[a]$ is the Pochhammer symbol. Now, in some odd piece of my work (physics) I somehow arrived at a series expansion that looks as:

$$\tilde{\Phi}(\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_N, \gamma, x_1, \ldots ,x_N) = \sum_{n_1,\ldots,n_N} \frac{(\beta_1)_{n_1} \cdots (\beta_N)_{n_N} }{(\gamma)_{n_1 + \cdots + n_N} n_1!\cdots n_N!} x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_N^{n_N} $$

which is like a multivariable expansion of the $\Phi_2$ function. I was wondering if anyone knows of a reference where this function is treated / defined / mentioned? Does it have a name? So far the only multivariable generalizations I found are the [Lauricella hypergeometric functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LauricellaFunctions.html), but this series isn't one of them.

Comment: Does anyone know how to compute Lauricella functions, implemented in any package? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a book that mentions the series I was talking about. It's the book [The H-function](http://books.google.nl/books?id=m8V8sYlb4UMC&pg=PR9&dq=fox%20h%20function%20book&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=MEN7T-rAL4mohAfKo807&ved=0CDsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=fox%20h%20function%20book&f=false), and in the appendix (not available through the link) they mention that the series is simply called the *confluent Lauricella hypergeometric series*.